# Catch TemplateDoesNotExist in django view

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to do something like the following instead of django trying to load a template here?

```
def 500(request):
    log.error('500 error')
    return HttpResponse(status=500)
```

Otherwise I get a:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

And I don't want to include a 500 or 404 template.

Comment: How to you configure error handling? Also I know that it is an example, but `500` is not a valid function name.

Comment: I just ran the function and didn't throw any error: 
`System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 24, 2018 - 03:18:16
Django version 2.1.1, using settings 'foo2.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /sandbox/err500/
[24/Sep/2018 03:18:19] "GET /sandbox/err500/ HTTP/1.1" 500 0`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use a custom view to handle server errors.

You can do this by setting the attribute `handler500` in your project `urls.py`, e.g.:

```
handler500 = 'myproject.views.handler500'
```

Here is the relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you for this.